# How to import Javascript library in angular2 globally

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, angular2-providers

I'm trying to import the moment.js library in angular2.
I found the following solution as:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: require('./app.component.html')
})
export class AppComponent {
  moment:any = moment;
  constructor() {}
}
```

However, I do not want to import this to every component I have. Is there a way to inject it globally so I can use it in all my components?

Answer (score 5):

Derive your components from a common base type that imports moment.

Parent

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

export class MomentAwareClass {
  moment:any = moment;
  constructor() {}
}
```

Child

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: require('./app.component.html')
})
export class AppComponent extends MomentAwareClass  {
  constructor() {}
}
```

## Update

A better way is to use [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) to write a service with the `Injectable()` decorator, this is better as composition is preferred over inheritance.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Injectable()
export class SomeClass {
    public moment: any = moment;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice approach. I'd like to wait to see if there are some other alternatives.

Comment: You can't inject something something that isn't marked as @injectable. Its just not possible with a 3rd party library like this, unless you wrap it inside a service angular understands. This is probably a better solution than what I described above, because its more compose-able.

Answer (score 5):

From what I read [here](https://blog.sstorie.com/providing-external-data-when-bootstrapping-angular-2/), I can provide the momentjs library when bootstrap the whole application like this:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

bootstrap(App, [
    provide("moment", {useValue:moment})
])
```

Then I can use it in my own component by using DI, like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Inject} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: require('./app.component.html')
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(@Inject("moment") private moment) {}
}
```